# Teaser is missing CKEditor when uncollapsed

Tags: entities, 8, wysiwyg

I have text with summary fields on my entity and for some reason the ckeditor is present only on the body, not on the teaser if I uncollpse it. What could be the issue?

Comment: I never use the summary, if I remember correctly, I think wysiwygs don't load on summary. (could be wrong).

Comment: Looks like my memory is good. I found this [screen shot](https://www.drupal.org/files/2011-09-30_12-36-39.png) in google images.

Comment: If only there was a way to turn on Rich Text Editor for Summary Fields...

Comment: I remember it worked on summary as well(though I think it might have been some alpha version of d8, don't know really and maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: See: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196161/how-to-change-text-format-of-summary-trimmed-field . You can't change the summary format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use "Text and summary" fields. It's a sad/unfortunate fact that Drupal 8 didn't manage to remove them.

Instead, create a *separate* (independent) summary field.