# How to change text format of summary/trimmed field?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, entities

Is there a straightforward way to change the summary/trimmed text to "full html" in Drupal 8?

There are workarounds such as creating separate body fields and using them as the summary but I am specifically asking about changing the text format of default summary/trimmed field of "Text (formatted, long, with summary)".

To put it another way, how to I add the CKEditor bar to the summary/trimmed text.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189511/teaser-is-missing-ckeditor-when-uncollapsed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, it always has the same format. The field only stores a single format. And it has bugs with ckeditor, as you've found.

I would definitely recommend to use two fields. We'd like to remove the text with summary field type, it's unnecessary complexity but it was too late for 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the twig template, works for me.

```
    {% autoescape false %}
      {{ node.body.summary}}
    {% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the key here is that the summary field will run the text through whatever filters you have enabled for the text format of the long text portion of the field.

I was able to add a `<p>` tag around my summary by enabling the **Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)** filter.